# why changing the root logger does not have affect on other loggers?

Tags: logging, log4j

Here is the `log4j.xml` that I use with my `spring` application.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"> 
    <appender name="PRIMARY" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <param name="FileNamePattern" value="/var/log/myappcontroller-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log"/>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ISO8601} %d %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>


<logger name="com.myapp.usercontroller" additivity="false">
        <level value=“INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="PRIMARY"/>
    </logger>


  <root>
        <priority value="INFO”/> //changing this to DEBUG
        <appender-ref ref="PRIMARY"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>
```

Two questions:

**1)** when I change the `priority value =DEBUG` in `<root>`, I was hoping to see debug logs from `com.myapp.usercontroller`. But I did not. why changing the `<root>` value did not have effect.

**2)** On the contrary, I start seeing the loggers `(org.apache.http)`

```
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 >> POST /token HTTP/1.1
```

Why is it so? I have not configured this logger. but changing the `<root>` has direct effect on this logger.

Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your explicit definition of the logger called `com.myapp.usercontroller` contains a threshold level parameter that is overriding the value that would otherwise have been inherited by the root logger. When you change the root logger's priority from INFO to DEBUG, then that will affect every logger *except* those loggers which have an explicitly configured value. That's why you see the DEBUG logs from `org.apache.http.headers`, but not for your controller.

Note that log4j xml is confusing in that it uses `priority` for the root logger, but `level` for the named loggers, even though they both refer to logging thresholds.

Comment: so debug level for `com.myapp.usercontroller` applies to `com.myapp.usercontroller.xxx` etc correct?

Comment: That's correct. The dots act as hierarchy separators.